# waitForNavigation hanging, even though page was loaded

Tags: puppeteer

I'm trying to automatically login to a website using puppeteer, with the following script:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
async function logIn(userName, password) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://foo.com'); //anonymized host
    await page.type('[name="Email"]', userName);
    await page.type('[name="Pass"]', password);
    page.click('[type=submit]');
    await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'load'});
}

logIn('user@domain.com')
```

The `await`for `waitForNavigation` eventually times out at 30 seconds. Launching puppeteer with `{headless: false}` on the same script, I can check in chromium's devtools that `document.readyState` evals to "complete" way before the timeout thresold interval. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[According to Puppeteer documentation](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.5.0/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options) proper pattern for clicking on submit and waiting for navigation is like this:

```js
await Promise.all([
  page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'load' }),
  page.click('[type=submit]'),
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've read about this race condition in https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1412 - that's why i'm only awaiting on the waitForNavigation. I'm not so sure why this snippet solves it, though - does waitForNavigation monitor _changes_ on document.readyState's value, so that it ignores the variable's value possibly being initiallly "complete"? This could happen if the first promise's execution begins before the click happens, right?

Comment: For me this won't solve anything, with a very similar initial situation as the example above.

Comment: Can you help as to why this method works?? I am having problem understanding.

Comment: `Promise.any` would work great in there, here's my implementation of your appreciated answer: `await Promise.any([ page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'load' }), page.click('body'), ])`

Answer (score 7):

Adding to the answer of Everettss, I would like to present a more modern code. Basically instead of doing any operation and calling `waitFornavigation`, the motive is to do the other way around. Something like this:

```
//Get the promise which isn't resolved yet
const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation(); 

//Perform the activity (Click, Goto etc). Note that the link is any valid url
await page.goto(link);

//wait until the navigationPromise resolves
await navigationPromise;
```

This helps to avoid race condition as per [this](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3338) discussion

This code makes use of async/await which is much more readable than promise-based code